# What is the Biblical basis for using the names "Yeshua" and "Yehoshua" (Joshua) for Jesus?

Tags: name-of-jesus, joshua, messianic-judaism

[Messianic Jews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messianic_Judaism) commonly refer to Jesus as "Yeshua" or "Yehoshua," which are forms of the Hebrew (and Aramaic) name commonly translated into English as "Joshua."

What is the Biblical basis for using these names for Jesus?

Comment: This sounds more like a language question

Comment: @Marc Yes, it *is* a language question. But it's a language question related to the beliefs and practices of a specific group, Messianic Jews, and about the Biblical basis of one of their practices. I think many people will find it interesting and useful to know the Biblical basis of that practice.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is, as noted, primarily a question about Semitic languages in the First Century. However, as it happens, there is a Biblical record of the relationship between the Semitic name *yĕhôšūaʿ* and the Greek *Iēsous*, the [diachronic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synchrony_and_diachrony) shift that produced *yēšûaʿ*, and the equation of *yēšûaʿ* with *Iēsous*.<sup>1</sup>

**Background**

The New Testament is in [Koine Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koine_Greek#Biblical_Koine). Jesus's name here is written as Ἰησοῦς (*Iēsous*).<sup>1</sup> However, it is generally accepted that [Jesus spoke primarily Aramaic and/or Hebrew](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/201/3555). Determining the precise sounds that Jesus and his friends used to pronounce his name (which is, I suppose, the basis of the preference of the group described in the question) entails speculation about the Hebrew or Aramaic name that corresponds to the Greek name recorded in the Gospels. In this case, whether they were speaking Hebrew or Aramaic is probably not so important. (See below.)

**Insights from Septuagint Joshua**

As noted in this question and [another related question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/46229/13677), the name *yĕhôšūaʿ* is used most frequently in the Bible to the man [who served as Moses's "assistant"](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=exodus%2024%3A13&version=ESV;WLC) during the wilderness period and subsequently led the Israelite people into Canaan, as recorded in the [eponymous book](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=joshua+1&version=ESV;WLC). This name is transliterated consistently into the Greek of [the Septuagint](http://www.septuagint.net) as Ἰησοῦς (*Iēsous*). *Yĕhôšūaʿ*, though, has an additional syllable compared to *yēšûaʿ*, so we remain one step away from a full explanation.

**Insights from Late Biblical Hebrew**

The Biblical books of Ezra, Nehemiah, and Chronicles provide the link we need. These books were composed during [the Persian period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_ancient_Israel_and_Judah#Persian_period) (539 - 332 BCE) and so occasionally provide information about the transition between the language of the earlier portions of the Hebrew Bible and the dialect spoken in the first century. In these books, the name *yĕhôšūaʿ* is used only once, in reference to Moses's assistant ([1 Chr 7:27](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20chr%207%3A27&version=ESV;WLC)). Otherwise, the name *yēšûaʿ* is used, most often (only?) to refer to the son of Jozadak, a man [referred to in Haggai and Zechariah](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=hag+1%3A12-14%3B+zech+3%3A1-10&version=ESV;WLC) as *yĕhôšūaʿ*. This occurs both in Hebrew and in the Aramaic portion of Ezra.<sup>2</sup>

Starting with Ezra 2:2:

> ESV: They came with Zerubbabel, **Jeshua**, Nehemiah...
>   Hebrew: *ʾăšer-bāʾû ʿim-zĕrubbāḇel **yēšûaʿ** nĕḥemyāh*...
>   Greek: *hoi ēlthon meta Zorobabel; **Iēsous**, Neemias*...

*Yēšûaʿ*, then, is a shortened form of *yĕhôšūaʿ* that was more commonly used later periods. In addition to being capable of an identical referent, both are translated identically into Greek: *Iēsous*.<sup>3</sup>

---

<sub>Notes</sub>

<sub>1. I use throughout the technical transliteration style [set out by the Society for Biblical Literature](http://opensiddur.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/07/SBL-Handbook-of-Style-Transliterating-and-Transcribing-Ancient-Texts.pdf). The transliterations in "normal" Latin characters offered in this question and others are no less "correct" (`š` = `sh`), but this system has the advantage of precisely representing each Hebrew consonant and vowel with 1:1 correspondence.</sub>

<sub>2. [In Hebrew](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ezra+2%3A2%2C+6%2C+36%2C+40%3B+3%3A2%2C+8-9%3B+4%3A3%3B+8%3A33%3B+10%3A18%3B+Neh+3%3A19%3B+7%3A7%2C+11%2C+39%2C+43%3B+8%3A7%2C+17%3B+9%3A4-5%3B+10%3A10%3B+12%3A1%2C+7-8%2C+10%2C+24%2C+26%3B+1+Chr+24%3A11%3B+2+Chr+31%3A15&version=ESV;WLC): Ezra 2:2, 6, 36, 40; 3:2, 8-9; 4:3; 8:33; 10:18; Neh 3:19; 7:7, 11, 39, 43; 8:7, 17; 9:4-5; 10:10; 12:1, 7-8, 10, 24, 26; 1 Chr 24:11; 2 Chr 31:15. [In Aramaic](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=ezra+5%3A2&version=ESV;WLC): Ezra 5:2.</sub>

<sub>3. As it happens, in the Septuagint the Greek translation of *yēšûaʿ* (*Iēsous*) behaves slightly more like the New Testament's *Iēsous* than does the Greek translation of *yĕhôšūaʿ*. Although identical in the nominative case, the Greek term is only partly declinable in the NT: the dative and genitive share the form *Iēsou*. This is also true in the Greek translations of *yēšûaʿ* in Chronicles, etc. On the other hand, the dative is (usually) distinguished in the book of Joshua (*yĕhôšūaʿ*) as *Iēsoî*.</sub>

Comment: Please forgive the deformed transliteration font -- quite ugly.  :-(

Comment: Would it bear any fruit to compare how Jesus is referred to in the Gospels of Mark and Luke versus the [Gospel of Matthew, which original version is/was/may have been written in Aramaic](http://www.catholic.com/quickquestions/was-matthews-gospel-first-written-in-aramaic-or-hebrew)

Comment: @Korvin Not sure.... I don't put much weight into the notion of the Aramaic primacy of Matthew myself (though I'm certainly no expert), but regardless, most of the references to Jesus in the Gospels are in reported speech, and much of this was probably originally in Aramaic anyway, so I'm not sure how "fruitful" it would be to try to tease out a difference according to a hypothesized difference in the phase at which the words were translated. (I would be more likely to see any such manifest differences as theological and/or literary in nature.) But did you have something in particular in mind?

Comment: What I had hoped might be known (but probably can't be since I know of no Aramaic text yet discovered of any of Matthew's gospel) would be the kind of word form the name for Jesus used in that Gospel (if it were first in Aramaic) would take in Aramaic versus Hebrew versus Koine Greek.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I think we have a pretty good handle on that information based on the consistent Septuagint translations  (2nd-3rd C. BCE) of both Hebrew and Aramaic *yēšûaʿ* as *Iēsous* (Greek, =Jesus). That this relationship between the names continued into the first century is testified in the NT, in Acts and Hebrews, when the character from the book of Joshua is referred to using this same Greek term.

Comment: That answers my question, thank you. (Oh, and sorry I forgot to upvote before.  Remedied).

Comment: @Susan Scholarly and impressive!

Comment: On a somewhat unrelated note, ['Joseph'](http://www.studylight.org/lexicons/hebrew/hwview.cgi?n=3130) is a shortened form of ['Jehoseph'](http://www.studylight.org/lexicons/hebrew/hwview.cgi?n=3084), which is only used once in [Psalm 81:5](http://www.studylight.org/desk/interlinear.cgi?search_form_type=interlinear&q1=Psalms+81%3A5&ot=bhs&nt=tr&s=0&t3=str_kjv&ns=0). Both names mean "Jehovah has added" and is further proof that shortened forms of names with "Ye-ho-" ("Je-ho" in English) existed in Hebrew before the Babylonian exile.

Comment: @Susan - After re-reading my comment I can see why you responded that way. What I was initially intending to say was that calling Jesus 'Yeshua' or 'Yehoshua' is fine, just like calling 'Joseph' by the fuller form of his name 'Jehoseph' is fine as well. It would be kind of similar to calling someone 'Matt' instead of his fuller form of his name 'Matthew.'

Comment: @BrianWeigand Gotcha, makes sense, sorry for misunderstanding. I was in the process of deleting and revising that comment anyway, so we'll just let it be.

Comment: So did the LXX translators get Iesous from Yeshua instead of Yahuwshuwa? Did they chose the post exile shorter form of his name instead of the older longer form?

Answer (score 4):

"For if Joshua had given them rest, He would not have spoken of another day after that."  Hebrews 4:8

"εἰ γὰρ αὐτοὺς ***᾿Ιησοῦς*** κατέπαυσεν, οὐκ ἂν περὶ ἄλλης ἐλάλει μετὰ ταῦτα ἡμέρας."  Hebrews 4:8

The easiest way to see the connection is to see that the Greek name "Jesus" really is the name Joshua in the Hebrew.  This can be seen in Acts 7:45 as well.

""And having received it in their turn, our fathers brought it in with Joshua (Jesus - Iēsous) upon dispossessing the nations whom God drove out before our fathers, until the time of David."  Acts 7:45

Ἰησοῦς

Iēsous

Thayer Definition:

Jesus = “Jehovah is salvation”

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).  Regarding this answer in particular, are you saying that the Greek word for Joshua in Acts 7:45 is the same word that is used in Greek for Jesus?

Comment: +1 for pointing out that "Joshua" is translated as ᾿Ιησοῦς when quoted from the OT to the NT.

Comment: On a related note, Joshua's name was originally Hoshea, [meaning "salvation"](http://www.studylight.org/lexicons/hebrew/hwview.cgi?n=1954) before [Moses gave him the more fitting name](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Numbers+13%3A16&version=NKJV) of Joshua/Jehoshua, [meaning "Jehovah is salvation."](http://www.studylight.org/lexicons/hebrew/hwview.cgi?n=3091)

Comment: Yes, what I was attempting to say that when in the context the word Iesous clearly means the historical Joshua the English translators translate it Joshua.  The fact is that every time that this Greek word appears it could have been translated Joshua.  So Joshua, the son of Mary is the Messiah.  

It is interesting that Hoshea was renamed Joshua.  

"These are the names of the men whom Moses sent to spy out the land; but Moses called Hoshea the son of Nun, Joshua."  Numbers 13:16

Answer (score 4):

In the Old Testament, the legendary military leader who led the conquest of the Promised Land was called Joshua, an English transliteration of the Hebrew יְהוֹשׁ֫וּעַ (Yĕhôshúʿa). In the Greek Septuagint (LXX), a pre-Christian translation of the Hebrew Bible into Greek, this name is always translated Ἰησοῦς - as we see, for example, here:

Joshua 1:10: καὶ ἐνετείλατο Ἰησοῦς τοῖς γραμματεῦσιν τοῦ λαοῦ λέγων
The Greek word Ἰησοῦς is pronounced /Iēsoūs/, from which we get 'Jesus', via Latin.

Translation in the opposite direction, likewise, would render our English word "Jesus" to the Hebrew יְהוֹשׁ֫וּעַ (Yĕhôshúʿa) via the Greek Ἰησοῦς (Iēsoūs).

Although the New Testament was written entirely in Koine Greek, we have a biblical basis for יְהוֹשׁ֫וּעַ (Yĕhôshúʿa) as Christ's Hebrew name via the Book of Joshua in Hebrew and Greek (LXX).

Comment: So did the LXX translators get Iesous from Yeshua instead of Yahuwshuwa? Did they chose the post exile shorter form of his name instead of the older longer form?

Answer (score -1):

We know for sure that 2000 years ago, they did not call our Messiah Jesus, because Jesus is a Latin name, and our Messiah was not Latin, but a Hebrew Rabbi.  I am for sure that his name was "Yeho" (shua), because he said in John 5:43, "I came to you in my Father's name," meaning His Father's name is "Yeho (vah).  And the first part of his name is His Father's abbreviated name "Yeho." And His Father removed the last part of his name, which is the (vah,) and replaced it with the Hebrew word "(shua)."  Because "shua" means, "(cry out to be save)." And because the Father "Yehovah," was going to save the world, through his son, he told us that "His Son's Name shall be called "Yeho (shua)," because Yeho means Yehovah, and shua means cry out to be save.  And when you put the meaning of both words together, which is the name, Yehoshua, it means,"Cry out to the Father Yehovah to be saved, in the name of his son, Yehoshua. Because the name of his Father Yehovah, who is doing the saving, is abbreviated Yeho, in the name of his Son Yeho (shua).

Comment: This answer could use some editing to alleviate the rambling, wall of text style.  Welcome the Christianity.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how an SE Q&A site works, particularly the [how to write a good answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) guidance.  Please revise your answer, for organization at the least, to improve it.  Once again Welcome, and we hope you'll browse a few more topics of interest to you.